# JavaScript document.forms[0].field.value compatibility

Tags: javascript, firefox, version, compatibility

I've a form with a raddioButton in IBM domino. The radioButton is to control the operation that user want to do. With JS I check that one option is selected before form will be send. I test it with Firefox Developer Edition (52oa) and works, but in client doesn´t work, he works with Firefox 31. My doubt is since wich version Firefox is compatible that method to get the value?
The code is this:

```
var control = document.forms[0].OperacionDNI.value;
if (control == 1 || control == 2) {
    guardar();
}
else{
    alert("Por favor, debe elegir una operación a realizar");
}
```

In my pc if one option is selected, call guardar() function, but in client PC shows the alert.

I think must be the method, any other idea will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it does not work on earlier versions of Firefox.

A simple workaround would be to select the element directly by it's id attribute.

```
var control = document.getElementById('OperacionDNI').value;
if (control == 1 || control == 2) {
    guardar();
}
else{
    alert("Por favor, debe elegir una operación a realizar");
}
```